# How to read the concatenated string as a variable in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-controller, angular-material

In my angular controller i defined

```
$scope.flag1 = false;
$scope.flag2 = false;
$scope.flag3 = false;
```

I need to read those variable in my view page as bellow

```
<div flex="30" flex-sm="100" ng-repeat="shortListLoad in user.shortListLoads">
 <md-icon id = "{{'flag'+shortListLoad.id}}">
 </md-icon>
</div>
```

The thing is id ="{{'flag'+shortListLoad.id}}" brings as id = 'flag2' than id= 'false'.

how to get id= 'false' ? please help me?

Comment: What does your `user.shortListLoads` look like?

Answer (score 1):

Another way is

```
<md-icon id = "flag{{id}}"> {{id}}</md-icon>
```

Working plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/1ufO3CJoUefVb2wDr4TZ?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right, you want to output to id flag1, or flag2 or flag3..

It's not recommended to use a function with angular binding, but you can do something like this.

```
$scope.getFlag = function(id){
    return 'flag'+id;
};
```

and in your view

```
 <div flex="30" flex-sm="100" ng-repeat="shortListLoad in user.shortListLoads">
     <md-icon id = "{{getFlag(shortListLoad.id)}}">
     </md-icon>
 </div>
```